# arcgis sketch module won't mount to DOM

Tags: vue.js, arcgis

I'm trying to include the arcgis sketch module in my vue app. For some reason when appending the sketch module my browser console log outputs an error that the 1st argument is not of type node then it fails to load the widget in the browser?

I'm not sure why this happens but I'm trying to follow the example code here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sketch-geometries/index.html

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadModules } from "esri-loader";
let E = {}; // placeholder for Esri modules

export default {
  name: "web-map",
  props: {
    coords: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      view: null,
      nodes: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // lazy load the required ArcGIS API for JavaScript modules and CSS
    loadModules([
        "esri/Map", 
        "esri/views/MapView", 
        "esri/geometry/Point", 
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch"], {
      css: true
    }).then(([ArcGISMap, MapView, Point, GraphicsLayer, Sketch]) => {
      E.ArcGISMap = ArcGISMap;
      E.MapView = MapView;
      E.Point = Point;
      var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

      const map = new E.ArcGISMap({
        basemap: "topo-vector"
      });

      this.view = new E.MapView({
        container: this.$el,
        map: map,
        center: [this.coords.latitude, this.coords.longitude],
        zoom: 9
      });

        // create a new sketch widget
        const sketch = new Sketch({
          view:this.view,
          layer: graphicsLayer
        });


       this.view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");
       map.add(graphicsLayer);


    });

  },
  watch: {
    coords() {
      this.showPos();
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.view) {
      this.view.container = null;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showPos() {
      if (E.Point) {
        const point = new E.Point(this.coords.longitude, this.coords.latitude);
        this.view.goTo({ center: point });
      } else {
        console.log("Map modules are still loading...");
      }
    },

    calcAvg(param){
      console.log('calc average',param)

      switch(param) {
          case 'wind':
            console.log('wind nodes',this.nodes)
            break;
          case 'rain':
            console.log('rain nodes',this.nodes)
            break;
          case 'elevation':
            console.log('elevation nodes',this.nodes)
            break;
          default:
            // code block
        }
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imports are not aligned. You have:

```js
loadModules([
        "esri/Map", 
        "esri/views/MapView", 
        "esri/geometry/Point", 
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch"], {
      css: true
    }).then(([ArcGISMap, MapView, Point, GraphicsLayer, Sketch])
```

Which means:
`esri/Map` -> `ArcGISMap`
`esr/views/MapView` -> `MapView`
`esri/geometry/Point` -> `Point`
`esri/Graphic` -> `GraphicsLayer`
`esri/layers/GraphicsLayer` -> `Sketch`
`esri/widgets/Sketch` -> Unassigned

You need to ensure that your `loadModules([])` array is in the same order as the `.then([])` array. Use this to make sure the components line up:

```js
loadModules([
        "esri/Map", 
        "esri/views/MapView", 
        "esri/geometry/Point", 
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch"], {
      css: true
    }).then(([ArcGISMap, MapView, Point, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Sketch])
```